# Routing with modules with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm working with HMVC with wiredesignz plugin and have the following url `mysite.com/login` and it views my login form. I have the form to post to the submit method in the login controller inside of the user module. I'm trying to figure out what the route would be for this to work because inside of the submit method I have it echoing a string for testing purposes. The first route works beautifully but the second route presents a 404 Page not found. Any thoughts on how to correct this.

```
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
$route['login/submit'] = 'user/login/submit';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by noticing that my submit function was named as a private function and not listed as public.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'user/login/$1';
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
```

or try to change the action of form to `submit`

```
$route['submit'] = 'user/login/submit';
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still received the same message.

Comment: Do you have other rewrites in `.htaccess` ?? can you add the code of .htaccess

Comment: Its just a very plane basic ci htaccess page

Comment: Mine worked the problem was that my submit function was a private not public function